# OpenXml throws a different exception given identical code and similar build configuration for two distinct solutions. Why?

Tags: c#, exception, openxml, .net-standard-2.0

Suppose I have two separate solutions in Visual Studio 2019:

- `openxml-exceptions.sln`
- `openxml-exceptions-reference.sln`

## `openxml-exceptions.sln`

This solution contains two projects:

- `basic-example`: A class library
- `call-basic-example`: A console app

### `basic-example`

The project file is as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>basic_example</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
      <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The project also contains `SpreadsheetWriterExample.cs`:

```
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Text;

namespace basic_example
{
   public class SpreadSheetWriterExample
   {

      public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
      {
         // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
         // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
         Console.WriteLine("creating spreadsheet document");
         try
         {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
               spreadsheetDocument.Close();
            }
         }
         catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("DirectoryNotFoundException");
         }
         catch (ArgumentException)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentException");
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("IOException");
         }
      }

      public static void Run()
      {
         
         CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook("asd\\da*dw.xlsx");
      }
   }
}
```

### `call-basic-example`

The project file is as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>call_basic_example</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\basic-example\basic-example.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The project also contains `Program.cs`:

```
using System;
using basic_example;

namespace call_basic_example
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {

         SpreadSheetWriterExample.Run();
      }
   }
}
```

## `openxml-exceptions-reference.sln`

This solution contains one project:

- `basic-example`: A console app

## `basic-example`

The project file is as follows:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>basic_example</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
      <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The project also includes `SpreadSheetWriterExample.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Text;

namespace basic_example
{
   public class SpreadSheetWriterExample
   {

      public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
      {
         // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
         // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
         Console.WriteLine("creating spreadsheet document");
         try
         {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
               spreadsheetDocument.Close();
            }
         }
         catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("DirectoryNotFoundException");
         }
         catch (ArgumentException)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("ArgumentException");
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("IOException");
         }
      }

      public static void Main()
      {
         
         CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook("asd\\da*dw.xlsx");
      }
   }
}
```

## Question:

When I build and run `openxml-exceptions.sln` with `call-basic-example` as the startup project, I get `DirectoryNotFoundException` in the output.

When I build and run `openxml-exceptions-reference.sln` I get `ArgumentException` in the output.

I am using the following version of Visual Studio:

[image]

Given that I am using the exact same framework version in the class library of `openxml-exceptions.sln` and the console app of `openxml-exceptions-reference.sln` and the exact same version of `OpenXml`, I cannot wrap my head around *why* the thrown and caught error are different for each solution. As far as I can tell they should be exactly the same, but I am apparently overlooking something fundamental.

Why are the errors thrown different for each solution, given the exact same code, framework version and package version?

Comment: Using the code provided in the OP, I'm unable to replicate the issue described. However, `*` is not permitted as part of a filename in Windows See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions). For two of the exceptions, you've followed a convention of `catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)`, but then have `catch (ArgumentException)`.

Comment: I'm intentionally providing an invalid file name. What I'm contesting here is the fact that I get a different exception when using `netstandard2.0` framework in different ways, which I don't think should happen. What kind of result were you getting when you tried to replicate the issue I described?

Comment: Seems like you left that detail out of your OP. I do notice that in `openxml-exceptions-reference.sln` that you have `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`. When I created the project that wasn't an option - only `.NET Core 3.1`. Also, when I referred to the [.NET Standard documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0) the word `library` is used frequently. How were you able to create the project as `.NET Standard 2.0`?